# Connect Android Studio to Arduino YUN

Tags: android-studio, arduino-yun

I am making a smart urban farm that has 3 sensors: moisture, water, and temperature. I am trying to send the values(digital/analog) via wifi-shield to the app itself. I am having a hard time finding a similar code that does this using wifi. What function in android studio would I use to get the information from the Arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can just directly send the data via wifi, but what I know you can do is writing the data from your arduino to database. Then, make your android app download the data from the same database. The database can be anything (Firebase, Drive or similar clouds)